# Magnolia5.5 deployment

Tags: magnolia

We are trying to deploy the .war file in Author instance and the deployment was successful. But when hitting the URL http://:magnolia-author getting the below error message. But the same .war file we have deployed in other environment and it is working fine. Can you please someone help me on this?

> Jul 14, 2017 4:01:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with
>   path [/magnolia-author] threw exception
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No configured callback accepted this
>   request
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.UnicodeNormalizationRequestWrapper@18fac90b
>           at info.magnolia.cms.security.SecurityCallbackFilter.selectClientCallback(SecurityCallbackFilter.java:114)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.security.SecurityCallbackFilter.selectAndHandleCallback(SecurityCallbackFilter.java:105)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.security.SecurityCallbackFilter.doFilter(SecurityCallbackFilter.java:86)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.security.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:94)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>           at info.magnolia.module.site.filters.SiteMergeFilter.doFilter(SiteMergeFilter.java:119)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>           at info.magnolia.multisite.filters.MultiSiteFilter.doFilter(MultiSiteFilter.java:110)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MultiChannelFilter.doFilter(MultiChannelFilter.java:83)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>           at info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.GZipFilter.doFilter(GZipFilter.java:73)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.security.auth.login.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:127)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>           at info.magnolia.enterprise.registration.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:64)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.UnicodeNormalizationFilter.doFilter(UnicodeNormalizationFilter.java:89)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CosMultipartRequestFilter.doFilter(CosMultipartRequestFilter.java:111)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>           at info.magnolia.personalization.preview.filter.PreviewFilter.doFilter(PreviewFilter.java:92)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>           at info.magnolia.personalization.trait.AbstractTraitDetectorFilter.doFilter(AbstractTraitDetectorFilter.java:80)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>           at info.magnolia.personalization.trait.AbstractTraitDetectorFilter.doFilter(AbstractTraitDetectorFilter.java:80)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>           at info.magnolia.personalization.trait.AbstractTraitDetectorFilter.doFilter(AbstractTraitDetectorFilter.java:80)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>           at info.magnolia.personalization.trait.AbstractTraitDetectorFilter.doFilter(AbstractTraitDetectorFilter.java:80)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContentTypeFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeFilter.java:155)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:128)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:65)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.doFilter(SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.java:107)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterDispatcher.doDispatch(MgnlFilterDispatcher.java:67)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:108)
>           at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:94)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No configured callback accepted this request

Seems like instance doesn't know how to treat the exact request/url you are entering. Perhaps you have some wrong configuration in your war file? Or perhaps you are trying to open url that is not supposed to work? Try to login to admin central directly with `http://your.domain/.magnolia/admincentral`